Why is the execution of a wolfram script `.wl` is slower in linux than in a macos?
I have a wolfram script that does the following tasks in the following sequence:

import 2 csv data files
make bunch of plots
save 4 PDF files of plots

I have licensed Wolfram14.1 installed on both of my computers. The machine specs are:
Linux
8 core - AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics + 16G RAM
MacOS
8-core CPU with 4 perform­ance cores and 4 efficiency cores - Apple Silicon M1 + 16G RAM (16 Core Neural Engine [Whatever it means!])
The problem occurs where I ran the same script with time command I got the following results, the time for linux machine is

the time taken for macos machine is

Summary:



machine
time




linux OS
2 min 37 secs


mac os
10 secs



Why is it taking so long time in linux?
p.s.: I also tried the free wolfram engine in linux and it also took the same time in linux machine.

I suggest you spread some Prints in your code and observe the execution so that you can pinpoint where exactly the bottleneck is. It might be launching the kernel, reading the files, exporting the PDFs ...

Please post the code and csv files so we can play around.

This time difference is not normal. Are you sure the script on macOS actually run and did what it is supposed to do? I knew macOS M1 was fast, but it can't be this much faster. something is off somewhere.  Is Mathematica itself that much faster on maxOS vs. Linux? If so, I am going out now and buying a macOS computer !
